# Check this SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, toad

```
select a.LOB, SUM(a.GPW) AS XGPW,SUM(b.GPW) AS YGPW,SUM(a.GPW) - SUM(b.GPW)     AS GPW_DIFF 
FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS a,

SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS b 
where a.LOB = b.LOB and
a.account_year=2014 and b.account_year=2015
GROUP BY a.LOB
```

I want to print the total GPW generated in the year 2014 and 2015. In Db, i have separate values of GPW for each month etc, i want to sum them all. For year 2014, the sum is correct but not for 2015. Suggestions please

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please comment if u need any other information

Comment: `a.account_year=2014 and b.account_year=2015` - this will never be true, as `account_year` cannot contain BOTH 2014 and 2015 at once. You might want to look at that...

Comment: Sir same table contains GPW from year 2014 and year 2015. I tried to pick 2014 one from a and 2015 from b

Answer (score 2):

Instead of joining the same table twice you better use CASEes:

```
SELECT LOB, XGPW, YGPW, XGPW - YGPW AS GPW_DIFF 
from 
 (
   select LOB, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN account_year=2014 THEN a.GPW ELSE 0 END) AS XGPW,
      SUM(CASE WHEN account_year=2015 THEN a.GPW ELSE 0 END) AS YGPW,
   FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS
   where account_year in (2014, 2015)
   GROUP BY LOB
 ) dt
```

Comment: Please remove the alias name `a` else it would throw error!

Comment: And yes you deserve a +1 for being faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `and` condition like this:

```
a.account_year in(2014,2015)
```

<strike>So it would be like</strike>

```
select a.LOB, SUM(a.GPW) AS XGPW,SUM(b.GPW) AS YGPW,SUM(a.GPW) - SUM(b.GPW)     AS GPW_DIFF 
FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS a,

SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS b 
where a.LOB = b.LOB and
a.account_year in(2014,2015)
GROUP BY a.LOB
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT LOB, XGPW, YGPW, (XGPW - YGPW) AS GPW_DIFF 
from 
 (
   select LOB, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN account_year=2014 THEN GPW ELSE 0 END) AS XGPW,
    SUM(CASE WHEN account_year=2015 THEN GPW ELSE 0 END) AS YGPW,
   FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS
   where account_year in (2014, 2015)
   GROUP BY LOB
 ) x
```

Comment: Still wrong. I need to calculate the sum of GPW of years 2014 and 2015 separately in different columns, not sum of both

Comment: @MohitaGakhar:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: Now it's the same as my answer :-)

Comment: @MohitaGakhar:- On a side note, please dont use the comma seperated joins as they are not recommended. Use proper JOINS instead. For example: `FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS a INNER JOIN 
SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS b 
ON a.LOB = b.LOB and`

Comment: @dnoeth:- Yes I see that. Your understanding was faster than me. I waited for OP to respond which took my time ;)

Comment: What about their difference? I want to print that too

Answer (score 1):

The "OR" require instead of "AND".

```
select a.LOB, SUM(a.GPW) AS XGPW,SUM(b.GPW) AS YGPW,SUM(a.GPW) - SUM(b.GPW)     AS GPW_DIFF 
FROM SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS a,

SDSS.DSS_SALES_PRODUCTION_DTLS b 
where a.LOB = b.LOB and
(a.account_year=2014 or b.account_year=2015)
GROUP BY a.LOB
```